# Mid westers leave the article out of their sentences!

Tags: articles

For instance:
Q: what do you do for a living?, 
A: I drive truck.(Not I drive a truck.)

I mowed lawn this weekend.
I drive bus.
I tend bar.
Etc.

This sounds incorrect to my Michigan native ears, is it correct English nevertheless?

Comment: "I tend bar" is normal in a lot of dialects, isn't it? Though I think "I'm a bartender" would be more common. The others sound wrong to me, though they may be normal in the dialect you are asking about. "I drive trucks" or "I drive buses" would be fine, but again "I'm a truck driver" seems more common..

Comment: I don't think you can produce an example of a Midwesterner saying "I drive truck" or "I mowed lawn."

Comment: The only one that sounds wrong to me is “I mowed lawn”.  The others are all normal and not just in the Midwest.

Comment: To my British ears "I drive bus" does not sound normal. In a BrEng dialect it would either be "I drive _a_ bus" or "I drive buses". Similarly "I mowed lawn" would be "I mowed _the_ lawn (or lawns)" if I was working in my own garden or "I mowed lawns" if I was working in a number of gardens for money. Only a few countable nouns can be treated as mass nouns in this way. For instance "I play guitar in a band", "I keep bar" (but not in Br English) and "I sing tenor". Apart from musical references I find it hard to think of any examples where a countable noun becomes uncountable in normal use.

Comment: I've lived in the Midwest my whole life, and I have never heard anyone leave out articles like in your examples, except by immigrants whose native languages do not have articles.